# wordpress plugin noob situation

Tags: plugins

Hay I am creating my first wordpress plugin. Everything is going well so far. I have been able to add a new navigation tab to the dashboard which links to a function which basicalliy uses 'include' to spit the content of a HTML page onto the wordpress admin area.

Heres my code

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'rooms_menu');

function rooms_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Rooms', 'Rooms', 'read', 'rooms-admin', 'show_hotel_dashboard', '' , 9);
}

function show_hotel_dashboard(){
    include 'dashboard.html';
}
```

pretty straight forward, the dashboard.html page is a very simple html page. Now, heres my issue, within this dasboard.html page, how do i link some links to functions?

Say i have a link which is

```
<a href='do_action.php'>Do action</a>
```

when i click that link it actually goes to do_action.php not the action within my plugin.

Any ideas?

Comment: *@dotty* - It would help everyone if you could give this a title that is more applicable to your question. That said, what do you mean by *"link some links to functions?"* And when you say *"it actually goes to do_action.php not the action within my plugin."* what actions are you talking about, WordPress actions? Where to you want it to go? The more clear you can make the question the better we'll be able to answer.

Comment: Voted question down because the title is so obscure and the question is unclear. I'll vote back up if the title and question are improved.

Comment: Voted down because of the description. The title is pretty fitting but much too broad as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than include an HTML file, include a PHP file instead.  Then, at the top of your PHP file you can check to see if any data's been submitted and process it before displaying the form.  So instead of what you have, try:

```
function show_hotel_dashboard(){
    include 'dashboard.php';
}
```

Then on the page do things like:

```
<a href="dashboard.php?action=do_something">Do something</a>
```

And in your `dashboard.php` file, start with

```
<?php
if($_POST["action"] == "do_something") {

    // Do something

} else {

    // Output your regular dashboard page

} ?>
```

Comment: This seems like a better way to do it rather than using wp_ajax and jQuery.

Comment: You might also want to review the Codex articles about creating options pages, particularly this one - http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus#Sample_Menu_Page ... it provides a concrete example of how to retrieve/act on `$_POST` data before doing anything with the UI.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you take a look at my [WordPress Plugin Template Creator](http://soderlind.no/wordpress-plugin-template-creator/) :)